# sorting array in object in mongodb is not working

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to sort data by dateTime.

sorting array in object in mongodb is not working

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$sort": {
      "values.dateTime": 1
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/-JtwQtIhxtl

Comment: This is what I have tried. It's not working

Comment: Have you looked at the linked answer? It works if you substitute in your field names: https://mongoplayground.net/p/7rE2In29eZG

Comment: As @MontgomeryWatts points out, the linked solution should work for OP's scenario. PramodKumar please help to provide specific details about **It's not working**

Comment: @montgomery watts    thanks.. Yes it's working. I got my mistake